# When or why should I use a Mutex over an RwLock?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, readwritelock

When I read the documentations of [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html), the difference I see is the following:

- `Mutex` can have only one reader or writer at a time,
- `RwLock` can have one writer or multiple readers at a time.

When you put it that way, `RwLock` seems always better (less limited) than `Mutex`, why would I use it, then?

Answer (score 79):

Sometimes it is better to use a `Mutex` over an `RwLock` in Rust:

## `RwLock<T>` needs more bounds for `T` to be thread-safe:

- `Mutex` [requires `T: Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#implementations) to be `Sync`,
- `RwLock` [requires `T` to be `Send` **and** `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#implementations) to be itself `Sync`.

In other words, `Mutex` is the only wrapper that can make a `T` syncable. I found a [good and intuitive explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5bx34b/mutex_vs_rwlock/d9t67cg/) in reddit:

> Because of those bounds, RwLock requires its contents to be Sync, i.e. it's safe for two threads to have a &ptr to that type at the same time. Mutex only requires the data to be Send, because conceptually you can think of it like when you lock the Mutex it sends the data to your thread, and when you unlock it the data gets sent to another thread.

Use `Mutex` when your `T` is only `Send` and not `Sync`.

## Preventing writer starvation

`RwLock` does not have a specified implementation because it uses the implementation of the system. Some read-write locks can be subject to [writer starvation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190090/how-to-prevent-writer-starvation-in-a-read-write-lock-in-pthreads) while `Mutex` cannot have this kind of issue.

`Mutex` should be used when you have possibly too many readers to let the writers have the lock.

Comment: Only a naive implementation of a reader/writer lock would allow writers to starve. If I was responsible for an application that would benefit from a reader/writer lock, and if I had to deploy it on some platform where the "standard" reader/writer lock was crap, then I would write my own---tailored to the needs of my application---rather than fall back to a simple mutex.

Comment: I would touch on *performance* and *intent* here. That is (1) RW Lock implementations are generally more complex, and thus slower and (2) if your algorithm only needs a Mutex, using a RW Lock is just confusing your readers for no benefits. Could even add correctness: if you paper around locking issues by just upgrading Mutex to RW Lock at random, you're toast. Multi-threading and Distributed programming require clear models of the data-flow; just throwing locks around randomly does not correct the flows magically.

Comment: Although the question is under 'rust' tag, I found the documentation on [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) interface in Java to have quite a comprehensive discussion on various things the _user_ must consider when choosing between a mutex and a read-write lock, and the possible implementation trade-offs.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev Thanks for your link! I must definitely take the time to enhance this answer.

Answer (score 11):

Mutex is a simple method of locking to control access to shared resources.

- At the same time, only one thread can master a mutex, and threads with locked status can access shared resources.
- If another thread wants to lock a resource that has been mutexed, the thread hangs until the locked thread releases the mutex.

Read write locks are more complex than mutex locks.

- Threads using mutex lack read concurrency.
- When there are more read operations and fewer write operations, read-write locks can be used to improve thread read concurrency.

Let me summarize for myself:

- The implementation of read-write lock is more complex than that of
  mutual exclusion lock, and the performance is poor.
- The read-write lock supports simultaneous reading by multiple threads. The mutex lock does not support simultaneous reading by multiple threads, so the read-write lock has high concurrency.