# Does std::shared_mutex favor writers over readers?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Since C++17(C++14) we have the std::shared_(timed_)mutex classes. 
Qt had an analogous class QReadWriteLock for a long time. QReadWriteLock's  [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qreadwritelock.html) says:

> To ensure that writers aren't blocked forever by readers, readers
>   attempting to obtain a lock will not succeed if there is a blocked
>   writer waiting for access, even if the lock is currently only accessed
>   by other readers. Also, if the lock is accessed by a writer and
>   another writer comes in, that writer will have priority over any
>   readers that might also be waiting.

As this is certainly a reasonable property, I wonder if 
[std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) and [std::shared_timed_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) behave in a similar way?

Comment: huh, what made you think I wanted to imply that the meaning of the question is not clear? Anyhow I agree that my answer is non-sense and deleted it

Comment: cpp reference doesn't state anything about – provided it doesn't differ from the standard in this respect (haven't looked up), implementation apparently is unspecified. So every compiler might handle it the way it wants. I personally would implement according to first come, first served, that appears the most natural to me...

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation of [shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) nor in [shared_timed_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) they mention readers/writers priority over locking. The only way to check this is the source code of the implementaiton.

Comment: @Tony Well, one could write a little test programme, too. But both would reveal only *your* compiler's implementation. Others might differ...

Comment: @Aconcagua indeed.

Comment: [Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.sharedtimedmutex.requirements) indeed doesn't seem to specify, unless I overlooked something.

Comment: If you need an open source reader/writer mutex that prioritizes waiting writers (non-recursive only):  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mutual-exclusion-c-between-single-writer-thread-multiple-walter-karas/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Official C++ Standard doesn't specify the `std::shared_mutex` policy. Explanation could be found in original N2406 proposal
(http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#shared_mutex_imp) in **shared_mutex Reference Implementation** section:

> A secondary motivation is to explain the lack of reader-writer priority policies in shared_mutex. This is due to an algorithm credited to Alexander Terekhov which lets the OS decide which thread is the next to get the lock without caring whether a unique lock or shared lock is being sought. This results in a complete lack of reader or writer starvation. It is simply fair.

Comparing to QReadWriteLock implementation (that is *write-preferring*):

> To ensure that writers aren't blocked forever by readers, readers attempting to obtain a lock will not succeed if there is a blocked writer waiting for access, even if the lock is currently only accessed by other readers.

That's true for proposal's `shared_mutex` as well, to make sure writer will not wait forever if new readers are continuing to come.

> Also, if the lock is accessed by a writer and another writer comes in, that writer will have priority over any readers that might also be waiting.

That's NOT true for proposal's `shared_mutex`, readers and writers have equal priorities in this case.

But unfortunately final C++ Standard document doesn't contain this reference implementation. Note that despite the fact GCC contains `std::shared_mutex` implementation that is based on N2406 reference implementation, but on Linux it's not used by default, it uses `pthread_rwlock_t` from POSIX threads lib (controlled by `_GLIBCXX_USE_PTHREAD_RWLOCK_T` option in `c++config.h`). `pthread_rwlock_t` can be read-preferring or write-preferring depending on system setup and applied `pthread` attributes. See related question for details: [How to prevent writer starvation in a read write lock in pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190090/how-to-prevent-writer-starvation-in-a-read-write-lock-in-pthreads)

Comment: Excellent information about GCC. Do you have similar findings about Clang?

Comment: @MiljenMikic actually this code is part of `libstdc++` library, so if Clang uses it (on Linux it's by default) - it shares the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Let me then rephrase the question: what about `libc++` library and the implementation of `shared_mutex` in it?

Comment: @MiljenMikic by default it's read-preferring.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't specified by the standard.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html) doesn't specify how pthread rwlocks must decide which lock request next succeeds, so it would be impossible to implement C++ `std::shared_mutex` in terms of standard pthreads if it had such a requirement.

> As this is certainly a reasonable property

It's certainly *a* reasonable property, but it's not the *only* reasonable property.

For example, GLIBC has a pthreads extension allowing you to choose from three rwlock policies: recursive prefer reader, recursive prefer writer and non-recursive prefer writer. Presumably *recursive prefer writer* isn't the correct choice for all programs.

---

> To ensure that writers aren't blocked forever by readers ...

As an aside, this does nothing to ensure that writers aren't blocked forever by *other writers*.

The intuitively-perfectly-fair solution is shared-reader-preferred-exclusive-FIFO-ordered-writer, but this is unnecessarily heavyweight for many purposes.

The Qt version may be exactly perfect for Qt's use case, but it is only one point on the light/efficient -- heavy/fair spectrum.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could mark two answers as the answer.