# Configure shared_mutex to prefer writer over readers

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, pthreads, locking

I have a C++ application compiled with gcc that uses `boost::shared_mutex`. I use them with `shared_lock` (reader) and `unique_lock` (writer).

I am running into writer starvation as explained in [Does std::shared_mutex favor writers over readers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706952/does-stdshared-mutex-favor-writers-over-readers).

The linked article says that POSIX threads lib is used and links to another article how `PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NONRECURSIVE_NP` can be used with pthreads. There is it described that I should initialize `pthread_rwlock_init` and set `pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np`. However, my pthread rw locks are created by boost, and therefore I cannot pass such custom configuration to it.

Is there a way to globally prefer writers over readers such that boost will pick it up and what would such code look like?

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Clone & own the `shared_mutex` gcc file in your project, the file is small and compiles out of the box and use the alternative implementation that is hidden behind the `_GLIBCXX_USE_PTHREAD_RWLOCK_T` flag which takes into account writer starvation.
`boost::shared_lock` and `boost::unique_lock` work out of the box with such an alternative implementation and the remaining application is not affected.